# How to set a non SQLAlchemy default type as utf8 bin

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

How can I set a non default SQLAlchemy type as `utf8_bin`, e.g:

```
class User(sa.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sa.Column(sqlalchemy_utils.UUIDType(binary=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())

    name = sa.Column(sa.VARCHAR(100, collation='utf8_bin'))
```

When I try to insert a new user I receive the error:

```
Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8 character string: '8FAE44'") rows += self.execute(sql + postfix)
```

I have try to connect to MySQL using `?charset=utf8` but it don't work. I have also find this [thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79317) about the error.

My MySQL version is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper, Python 3.6.5, SQLAlchemy 1.2.15, SQLAlchemy Utils 0.33.10...

Comment: Don't you want to `default=str(uuid.uuid4()).encode()`?